# Enumerating 'sendas' permissions in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook

I am developing an Outlook 2010 addin and need to present the user with a list of accounts for which they have sendas permissions. OOTB, when you create a new mail, you can change the 'from' address and you get a nice neat list of all accounts you have access to send from. I basically need to be able to get that list using c# and am having trouble finding where it might be.

Any ideas?